# Is there a method with R function duplicated() for a sparse matrix from {Matrix}?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Is there an easy way to write a method for `duplicated` to take a `dgCMatrix` class? Here is a small example and the desired output is 
that of `which(duplicated(as.matrix(A), MARGIN = 2))`.

```
# assign example
library(Matrix)
i <- c(1,     3:7, 2, 1, 2, 3)
j <- c(2,  1, 3:6, 1, 7, 8, 8)
x <- c(1:7, 1, 7, 2)
(A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x))
#R 7 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#R 
#R [1,] . 1 . . . . 1 .
#R [2,] 7 . . . . . . 7
#R [3,] 2 . . . . . . 2
#R [4,] . . 3 . . . . .
#R [5,] . . . 4 . . . .
#R [6,] . . . . 5 . . .
#R [7,] . . . . . 6 . .

# column 7 and 8 match with 1 and 2
which(duplicated(as.matrix(A), MARGIN = 2))
#R [1] 7 8

duplicated(A)
#R Error in duplicated.default(A) : duplicated() applies only to vectors
```

The matrix I work with is rather large though so I would like to avoid converting the matrix into a dense one. For the same reason the function should also be fast.

My best bet so far is to look at [the code for `duplicated`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/c7593225c957bb5797b277a35efcb56bcfaa959c/src/main/unique.c#L433-L565) and maybe write an equivalent function with `Rccp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thought is to restore this sparse matrix into a list, `RowLst` or `ColLst`, such that `Rowlst[[i]]` or `ColLst[[i]]` is the compressed vector for the i-th row or column. Then apply `duplicated` on this list.

```
duplicated.dgCMatrix <- function (dgCMat, MARGIN, include.all.zero.vectors = TRUE) {
  MARGIN <- as.integer(MARGIN)
  J <- rep(1:ncol(dgCMat), diff(dgCMat@p))
  I <- dgCMat@i + 1
  x <- dgCMat@x
  if (MARGIN == 1L) {
    ## check duplicated rows
    names(x) <- J
    if (include.all.zero.vectors) {
      RowLst <- split(x, factor(I, levels = 1:nrow(dgCMat)))
      } else {
      RowLst <- split(x, I)  ## will do `factor(I)` internally in `split`
      }
    result <- duplicated.default(RowLst)
    } else if (MARGIN == 2L) {
    ## check duplicated columns
    names(x) <- I
    if (include.all.zero.vectors) {
      ColLst <- split(x, factor(J, levels = 1:ncol(dgCMat)))
      } else {
      ColLst <- split(x, J)  ## will do `factor(J)` internally in `split`
      }
    result <- duplicated.default(ColLst)
    } else {
    warning("invalid MARGIN; return NULL")
    result <- NULL
    }
  result
  }

which(duplicated.dgCMatrix(A, 2))
#[1] 7 8
```

---

Discussion between [20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) and me reveals something that is worth commenting.

1. I did not realize that with the above self-defined function, S3 method dispatching works for the S4 object. So, `which(duplicated(A, 2))` suffices.
2. `duplicated.matrix(t(A))` and `duplicated.array(A, MARGIN = 2)` return the right result here as well. At first we thought we found a hidden treasure, but by checking their source we see that they both rely on `apply`, which would do an `as.matrix` on a two-dimensional input object.

---

OP had a nice spot on his application. The original solution does not take all-zero rows / columns into account. The new version with added argument `include.all.zero.vectors` solves this. Basically we control factor levels used for `split`, so that an all-zero row / column is assigned an `NULL` entry in the list rather than being ignored.

Comment: Nice solution and nice use `names` which are kept by `split` so that e.g., `i <- c(1, 3:7, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2); j <- c(2, 1, 3:6, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9); x <- c(1:7, 1, 7, 2, 1); A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)` still gives the correct result (though at the cost of storing a `character` instead of an `integer`).

Answer (score 1):

[李哲源's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457395/5861244) works well except for when there are pure zero columns. E.g.,

```r
library(Matrix)
i <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1)
j <- c(1, 2, 4, 4, 6)
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
(A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x))
#R 2 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#R 
#R [1,] 1 1 . 2 . 1
#R [2,] . . . 3 . .

which(duplicated(as.matrix(A), MARGIN = 2))
#R [1] 2 5 6
which(duplicated.dgCMatrix(A, 2))
#R [1] 2 4
```

A slight modification though solves this

```r
duplicated.dgCMatrix <- function (dgCMat, MARGIN) {
  MARGIN <- as.integer(MARGIN)
  n <- nrow(dgCMat)
  p <- ncol(dgCMat)
  J <- rep(1:p, diff(dgCMat@p))
  I <- dgCMat@i + 1
  x <- dgCMat@x
  if (MARGIN == 1L) {
    ## check duplicated rows
    names(x) <- J
    RowLst <- split(x, I)
    is_empty <- setdiff(1:n, I)
    result <- duplicated.default(RowLst)
  } else if (MARGIN == 2L) {
    ## check duplicated columns
    names(x) <- I
    ColLst <- split(x, J)
    is_empty <- setdiff(1:p, J)
    result <- duplicated.default(ColLst)
  } else {
    warning("invalid MARGIN; return NULL")
    result <- NULL
  }
  
  if(any(is_empty)){
    out <- logical(if(MARGIN == 1L) n else p)
    out[-is_empty] <- result
    if(length(is_empty) > 1)
      out[is_empty[-1]] <- TRUE
    result <- out
  }
  
  result
}
```

after which we get

```
which(duplicated.dgCMatrix(A, 2))
#R [1] 2 5 6

# check that it works with the transpose
which(duplicated.dgCMatrix(t(A), 1))
#R [1] 2 5 6
```